# I want to compare two list and print the difference output from list one

Tags: shell-script, test

I have two variables 
input:

```
VAR1="abc red blue cat empty dummy rummy"
VAR2="rummy zero empty rat cat reverse"
```

output:
I want output as follows: (remove the common ones from `$VAR2` in `$VAR1`)

```
abc red blue dummy
```

I tried as follows:

```
for i in $VAR1
do
        for j in $VAR2
        do
                if [ $i != $j ]; then
                        echo $i;
                fi
        done
done
```

Here, `if [ $i == $j ]; then echo $i`, here I get output perfectly as `cat empty rummy`
But I need to get output other than these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
    a=()
    for i in $VAR1; do
        found=
        for j in $VAR2; do
            if [ $i == $j ]; then
                found=1
                break
            fi
        done
        if [ ! $found ]; then
            a+=($i)
        fi
    done
    echo ${a[*]}
```

In words: For every `i` in `VAR1`, compare it against every `j` in `VAR2`. If no match is found, add `i` to the output.

This version is assuming the characters in `VAR1` and `VAR2` won't be confusing the shell. Also, it is inefficient running in quadratic time, but maybe that's not a concern.

Faster, using [associative arrays](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays):

```
declare -A a2
for k in $VAR2; do
    a2[$k]=1
done
for k in $VAR1; do
    if [ ! "${a2[$k]}" ]; then
        echo $k
    fi
done
```